# Difference of behavior between “set -e + source” and “bash -ec + source”

Tags: bash

## Context

While setting up a basic unit testing system, I ran into an odd issue.
My goal was to make sure all individual test scripts:

- were run with `set -e` to **detect errors**, **without needing to explicitly set this** in each file;
- knew right away about the **functions to be tested** (stored in another file) **without needing to explicitly source** those in each test file.

## Observations

Let this be a **dummy test file** called `to-be-sourced.sh`. We want to be able to know **if a command in it fails**:

```sh
# Failing command!
false

# Last command is OK:
true
```

And here is a **dummy test runner**, which must run the test file:

```sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

if (
    set -e
    . to-be-sourced.sh
)
then
    echo 'Via set: =0'
else
    echo 'Via set: ≠0'
fi
```

This yields `Via set: =0`, meaning that the runner is happy. But it should not!
My hypothesis was:

> `set -e` is not propagated within `.` sourcing, and as explained in the help for `.` and `source`, the exit status is the one of the last command.

But then I came up with a workaround that works, but *also relies on `.`*:

```sh
if bash -ec '. "$0"' to-be-sourced.sh
then
    echo 'Via bash: =0'
else
    echo 'Via bash: ≠0'
fi
```

This yields `≠0` whenever a command in the test file fails, regardless of whether that command was the last one of the test file. As a bonus, I can toss any number of `. a/library/file.sh` within the `-c` command, so each test file can use all of my functions out of the box. I should therefore be happy, but:

**Why does this work, considering that the `-c` command also relies on `.` to load the test file (and I thought `bash`’s `-e` was equivalent to `set`’s `-e`)?**

I also thought about using `bash`’s `--init-file`, but it appeared to be skipped when a script is passed as a parameter. And anyway my question is not so much about what I was trying to achieve, but rather about the observed difference of behavior.

## Edit

Sounds like `if` is tempering with the way `set -e` is handled.

**This** halts execution, indicating **failure**:

```sh
. to-be-sourced.sh
```

… while **this** goes into the `then` (not the `else`), indicating **success**:

```sh
if . to-be-sourced.sh
then
    echo =0
else
    echo ≠0
fi
```

Comment: This is precisely the kind of distinction that supports the argument to *not* use or rely on `-e`. You might want to read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105.

Comment: @chepner Yeah, I generally take it with a grain of salt and don’t like it that much… outside of tests, where it allows you to write nice assertion-like instructions with `test` and co., with no need to spam with `|| exit`.

Comment: That's the thing. It *would* be nice... if you could rely on it working the way you expect. :/

Comment: I still think it can come in handy in a `( … )` (to avoid breaking stuff globally) when you need to execute stuff in succession and don’t want to flood your script with `&&`-s. But yeah, the more I write scripts, the less I like `-e`. And this question I asked is still nagging me. xD

Comment: As a fairly lame handwavy argument, the biggest distinction between the two is that there is a *process* boundary being crossed in the workaround that "shields" the `-e` option from the `if` statement it ultimately executes in.

Comment: I saw various scripts that had `[[ $exit_on_error ]] && set -e`, which were called with `exit_on_error=on ./script.sh`, but I have to say that sourcing a script that has a `set -e` is insane, unless you do it in a subshell

Comment: @chepner Why “lame”? It sounds plausible to me and could possibly be a valid answer.

Comment: I wrote up an answer that I think is less hand-wavy.

Comment: @Fravadona Yeah indeed, you can end up with your terminal closing and stuff xD But the goal was to keep `set -e` _outside_ of the individual test file. Furthermore, I indeed source those in subshells. I add `-x`, catch stderr and stdout, and only print it for failing test files. It’s actually pretty nice! As a dirty SO-comment-friendly single line: `if output=$(bash -exc '. "$BASEDIR"/lib/constants.sh; . "$BASEDIR"/lib/functions.sh; . "$0"' "$path" 2>&1); then echo '[OK]'; else echo '[Failure]'; printf '%s\n' "$output"; failure_paths+=("$path"); fi`

Comment: You have hit the answer. `man bash` explains for sourced files, `"The return status is the status of the last command exited within the script (0 if no commands are executed), and false if filename is not found or cannot be read."` There are no caveats for POSIX mode clearing `-e`, etc... The file is simply sourced and the return is the return of the last command read. You are wanting a `source [option] file` where you can pass `-e` as an options, but `source` doesn't except options. It just does what it does. (UV for well asked and formatted question)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, I took a look at the help for `source` and `.` and saw that indeed no such thing existed. Funnily enough, if you try to use an option, it tells you `invalid option`, making it sound as if _some options_ could be valid.

Comment: It's like you would think they could include it all in a 4800+ line `man bash`, but there is only so much time for documentation `:)` Best approach is to read man-pages literally. If they explicitly tell you you can do something, then it is a safe bet you can. If the man page is silent on any area, the safe bet is that the wished for feature doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This may not be precisely correct, but I think it captures what happens.)

In your first example, `set -e` sets the option in a command that is *lexically* in the scope of an `if` statement, and so even though it is set, it is ignored. (You can confirm it is set by running `echo $-` inside `to-be-sourced.sh`. Note, too, that `.` itself has a 0 exit status, which you can confirm by replacing `true` with an `echo` statement; it's not that it fails but the failure is ignored.)

In your second example, `-e` sets the `errexit` option in a new *process*, which knows nothing about the `if` statement and therefore it is not ignored.

Comment: I’ll wait a couple of hours / days to see if anyone comes up with something radically different before accepting, but thanks a lot already. Just to be clear: when you mention `echo`, you mean “with a string, to see it appear and confirm it has been run”? In my real case such things were hard to see as I was catching the output and flooding with `set -x`, hehe. But yeah I kinda knew everything was run, otherwise the sourcing would not benefit from the “hey the last command I ran was OK”, I guess. That was more or less what made this approach worthless.